# Show Monaco completion list even if there are no matches

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, monaco-editor

I have a custom `CompletionItemProvider` for Monaco editor.
Is it possible to force Monaco show the completion list even if there are no matches?

For example, imagine that I always provide two completion items: `abc` and `def`:

- If the user types `a`, then `abc` is shown
- If the user types `d`, then `def` is shown
- But if the user types `z`, then nothing is shown at all. Which makes sense by default. 
  But how can I make both `abc` and `def` appear in this case anyway?

The use case is that our users might not be aware of using ctrl+space to trigger completion, so we would like to present completion list even if nothing matches so that the users can explore the options and possibly correct themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Your completion provider is called on every time a user types a letter. Let's assume you built a super simple provider that just returns ['abc', 'def'] each time it's called.

In that case you'll get the behavior you observe. Why? Because what triggered the provider is the user typing 'a' or 'd' or 'z' or something. If they type 'a' you'll only see 'abc' and if they type 'd' you'll only see 'def', and you'll get nothing if they type 'z'

If you want you can specify another trigger character, like space, or '.' that will open the entire list.

```
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('javascript', {
    triggerCharacters: ['.', ' '],
    provideCompletionItems: ...
  });
```

Comment: Not sure this is how it works. The completion provider is called always, regardless of what the user types. So if the user types 'o' or 'z', provideCompletionItems() gets called. I always return ['abc', 'def'] from the function, but these values get filtered out later by Monaco because they don't match the 'o' or 'z' which is already typed.
You can test it in the [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-completion-provider-example). If you add triggerCharacters: ['o'] and type 'o', no completion items get shown.

Comment: Add `triggerCharacters: [' '],` to the playground example. Hit 'run', then type a space in that json example. You'll see all the possible autocompletes open up.

Comment: Yes, space shows all possible autocompletes only because there is no "current" word under the cursor. So the completion list does not filter itself.
If you change to `triggerCharacters: ['z'],` then no autocompletes will be shown since none of them start with 'z'. And this is what I need - show all autocompletes when 'z' is typed.

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood the question. In the playground you can add a filterText parameter to the completion result list. Try `filterText: 'z"lodash": "*"'` By putting 'z' in your filter text then it'll be matched and open the list. In your example it would be `filterText: 'zabc'` and `filterText: 'zdef'`

Comment: Thanks, that actually might work. But then I will need to adjust filterText dynamically based on what the user typed. For example, if the user typed 'zxc', then all completion items should have filterText starting with zxc :)
I hoped there would be an easier way to configure this, but it seems like there isn't really...